# Appending content to li elements from JSON array

Tags: javascript, json

I've an unordered list of 4 items and I want to add to each li element a div with class "meta", this div contain h2 and p elements that should be filled from a JSON array.

```
<ul id="list">
  <li>
    <div class="meta">
       <h2>Title here</h2>
       <p>Some description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="meta">
       <h2>Title here</h2>
       <p>Some description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="meta">
       <h2>Title here</h2>
       <p>Some description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="meta">
       <h2>Title here</h2>
       <p>Some description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
var nums = document.getElementById("list");
var listItem = nums.getElementsByTagName("li");
var listItemElement =  document.querySelectorAll("li");

var output;
for (var i in data.info) {
    output+="<div class='meta'>";
    output+="<h2>" + data.info[i].title +"</h2>";
    output+="<p>" + data.info[i].desc +"</p>";
    output+="</div>";

    for (var x = i; listItem.length; x++) {
      listItem[x].appendChild(output); 
    }

    //clear the object after every append
    output = "";
}
```

In the Javascript code I tried to add a loop inside the main one, so when the output object is filled, it should be appended to the current li element.

You can find the JSON array and Live code [here](http://codepen.io/shadeed/pen/a61831945bcdfc915cb3c5544669462e?editors=101)

How the code should work?
It should take every item from the JSON array and append it to the li element and so until it reaches the last one.

In my case I got an empty list with no data filled in it.

Any help with that please?

Comment: "The code is not working as expected." is a bad statement on SO. Tell us what it is doing and what it is supposed to be doing.

Comment: So, are you trying to add each data item to *one* `li`? If so, why loop over the `li` elements at all? (Notwithstanding the bug here, where the inner loop will never end, since `listItem.length` will always be true)

Comment: (In chrome at least) if you check your js console you will find an error message.  "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."  `appendChild` does not take a string as a parameter, it takes a node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming what you actually want to do is to add each item to *one* respective `li`, there's no inner loop needed.

Since you're not using jQuery, you can't append an HTML string -- but in this case, `innerHTML` will work fine, since the `li` elements are already empty and we don't need to preserve any existing contents.

```js
var data = {
  "info": [{
    "title": "Title Here",
    "desc": "This is some info about this item, it ranges from 20 to 30."
  }, {
    "title": "Title Here 2",
    "desc": "This is 2 some info about this item, it ranges from 20 to 30."
  }, {
    "title": "Title Here 3",
    "desc": "This is 3 some info about this item, it ranges from 20 to 30."
  }, {
    "title": "Title Here 4",
    "desc": "This is 4 some info about this item, it ranges from 20 to 30."
  }]
}

var nums = document.getElementById("list");
var listItem = nums.getElementsByTagName("li");

for (var i in data.info) {
  var output = "<div class='meta'>" +
    "<h2>" + data.info[i].title + "</h2>" +
    "<p>" + data.info[i].desc + "</p>" +
    "</div>";

  var li = listItem[i];

  li.innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

If your `data` may contain `<` or other HTML characters, you'll want to insert the text as TEXT nodes instead of HTML:

```
for (var i in data.info) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'meta';

  var h2 = document.createElement('h2');
  var ht = document.createTextNode(data.info[i].title);
  h2.appendChild(ht)

  var p = document.createElement('p');
  ht = document.createTextNode(data.info[i].desc);
  p.appendChild(ht)

  div.appendChild(h2);
  div.appendChild(p);

  var li = listItem[i];

  li.appendChild(div);
}
```